# Replacing text with regex using ".*" and $1

Tags: c#, regex

```
string pattern = @"<p>.*<br>";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
r.Replace(pattern, "<p>$1</p>");
```

The above code is supposed to find and replace the following `<p>` and `<br>` tags with `<p>` and `<p>` while keeping the text in between them. This will replace `<p>` and `<br>` but will replace the middle with "$1" instead of the appropriate text. I'm used to writing RE in Python which seems to be quite different.

Comment: That would not work in Python either. You need ()

Comment: I tried using (.*). The result is (.*).

Comment: I did, what should it look like?

Comment: Added answer... And it should be pretty much same in Python.

Comment: That was the first way I tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: What does your declaration of r look like? Your pattern variable is being passed as the 'input' parameter and we don't know what your pattern actually looks like…

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So, where is the input string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems to solve:

- Add `()` in pattern to get capture group
- Pass input to replace method
- Store result in variable (note: C# strings are immutable).

Fixed code:

```
string pattern = @"<p>(.*)<br>";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string output = rgx.Replace(input, "<p>$1</p>");
```